# How to prove an event is impossible to happen?

Tags: probability

I have known that null event and the event (for example $A$) that has $P(A)=0$ is not analogous. Consequently, how to prove that an event is impossible to happen, because $P(A)=0$ is not enough.

Comment: If the event is not in sample space it is impossible

Comment: Then you must have some other argument which shows that the conditions which define $A$ are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Probability theory does not deal with this question, since a probabilistic setup $(\Omega,{\cal F},\mu)$ contains no information about the true reasons why some events you might think of are so seldom that their probability is $0$.

Comment: @DeepeshMeena An event is a *subset* of the sample space, not an *element*. Therefore it does not make sense to speak of whether an event is "in" the sample space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We usually define our probability problem as a triplet $\Omega$, $\Sigma$, $\mu$ where

- $\Omega$ is the [sample space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_space)
- $\Sigma$ is the [$\sigma$-algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma-algebra) of our experiments, it contains all the possible events.
- $\mu : \Sigma \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$ is the [probability measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_measure) that maps an event to its probability.

The probability of an event $A\in \Sigma$ is $\mu(A)$, but this event may happen with probability zero. What you want to prove is that the set $A\notin \Sigma$. You must be careful when you define $\Sigma$ to be minimal in some sense.

Comment: By definition, $A$ must be an element of $\Sigma$ for $A$ to be an event...